# Get the current node page's pager number?

Tags: drupal, pager

How can I get the current node page's pager number? Is there a function that can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 and higher have a built in function, called [pager_find_page();](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_find_page/7).

Answer (score 0):

How about Ajax, I design a form with back - next button, how can we know the current page.

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been solved:
If for example I have passed a parameter to the page(http://www.example.com?page=1) , then I get the page number of the current node with .

```
$page_number = $_GET['page'];
```